# How to iterate all mill targets in build.sc, how to get target.dest from outside the target?

Tags: scala, ammonite, mill

I would like to write a `mill` utility tool (maybe a function or Module inside `build.sc`) for summarizing and post processing results of various targets. Instead of hard coding all processed targets I prefer a solution that could somehow iterate the `build.sc` contents and produce a list of found targets from which I could then filter out e.g. other than `ScalaModule`s etc.

What is the most elegant way to implement this kind of iterator?

That utility tool also needs to locate the `dest` directory of each target. Inside the target I can use `T.dest` but how the get the destination directory from "outside" (not running the target)?

One way to accomplish this kind of functionality is to browse recursively the directory structure under `./out` but that information lacks the target type information and also target `out` directory is missing if it is cleaned or not yet run at all. So it is not possible to report that target `Foo` exists but has currently no results.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just interested in the list of modules and targets, you can simple use the `resolve` command.

```
$ mill resolve __
```

To apply advanced filtering, you need to do it in Scala.
Mill already provides various support to access modules and targets.
Just have a look at the class `mill.define.Module`, which is inherited from all Mill modules. As an example: to access direct sub modules of a module `foo`, use `foo.millModuleDirectChildren`. You can find more in `foo.millInternal`, e.g. `modules` to find all sub modules, or `targets` to find all targets.

You can also look at the implementation of the various built-in commands in `mill.main.MainModule`. There you find various resolvers. You could even write your own to filter whatever you want. But be warned, it's far from trivial.

About the `dest` directory. In general, you shouldn't even want to access this directory. It is considered an implementation detail of a target. If you have the current `mill.eval.Evaluator` at hand (e.g. within an [evaluator command](https://com-lihaoyi.github.io/mill/mill/Extending_Mill.html#_evaluator_commands_experimental)) to retrieve the actual used `out` directory, you can get the actual path used for `T.dest` of a target with `mill.eval.EvaluatorPaths.resolveDestPaths`.

But instead of using this, you should just use whatever a target returns. There is no necessity e.g. for a `compile` target, that the actual compile result is located in its `T.dest` directory. Also, beware to not modify the `dest` directory or it's contents from outside, as that may break the caching mechanism.

I'm referring to the latest released Mill version 0.10.5.

Comment: I can get `mill resolve __` to work, but not `mill __.resolve` ...

Comment: You are completely right, I meant `mill resolve __`. This was a typo. I'll correct it. Thank you!